# Adding an item to cart, which is already added with another count

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, map-function, spread-syntax

I am building an eCommerce app, and with the below code I'm implementing the add to cart functionality.
The tricky part is when I try to add an item to cart that's already added with a different count.

So in the below code, I'm not
able to understand "**if(existItem) {...}**" part. This block is supposed to handle the above mentioned
case.

```js
import {
  CART_ADD_ITEM,
} from '../constants/cartConstants'
export const cartReducer = (state = {
  cartItems: []
}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CART_ADD_ITEM:
      const item = action.payload
      const existItem = state.cartItems.map(x => x.product === item.product)
      if (existItem) {
        return {
          ...state,
          cartItems: state.cartItems.map(x => x.product === existItem.product ? item : x)
        }
      } else {
        return {
          ...state,
          cartItems: [...state.cartItems, item]
        }
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good test. It will be true even when empty

```js
const cartItems = []
const existItem = cartItems.map(x => x.product === item.product)
if (existItem) console.log("Truthy")
```

Instead:

```js
const cartItems = []
const existItem = cartItems.map(x => x.product === item.product)
if (existItem.length>0) console.log("Items")
else console.log("Empty")
```

Or faster because it returns immediately if found:

```js
const cartItems = [{product:"fish"}]
const item = { product:"fish" }
const existItem = cartItems.find(x => x.product === item.product)
if (existItem) console.log("Item found")
else console.log("Empty")
```

Comment: I get your idea, but I want to understand the original code and whether it serves the purpose of increasing the quantity of that product. In short, does the length of cartItems change after the if block ? Also, existItem will be false when it is empty

Comment: I do not understand the question. The code you show will always perform the if part regardless of cart contents

Comment: think you are thinking of `filter` instead of `map`

Comment: @mplungjan yes, but my ques. is does the conditional statement inside the if block, change the length of cartItems array?

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial No, I want to retain the previous items in cart, hence filter cannot be used.

Comment: `cartItems: state.cartItems.map(x => x.product === existItem.product ? item : x)` will return the exact same number of items it contained before the statement. Some may be undefined or empty string

Comment: `arr = arr.map()` will always contain the same number of entries (unless you perform a delete inside the map code)

Comment: @mplungjan That's right. Also, existItem is same as item, so isn't  cartItems: state.cartItems.map(x => x.product === existItem.product ? item : x) statement useless ?

Comment: Certainly. I did not see that `const item = action.payload` is setting item to the cartItems - if that is the case

Comment: as existItem conveys a boolean meaning, wouldn't be crearer to do

    `const existItem = cartItems.some(x => x.product === item.product)
    if (existItem) {`